# Extract Dataframe from nested html table structure?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

### I wonder if there is a way to extract a dataframe from a nested Html structure/ code like the Pandas read_html() method.

Here is the html from which i need to extract all columns that come after the column "**action**". **Data.html:**

```
<table border="1"><tr><th>Central Repository</th><td><table border="1"><tr><th>Passadena-USA</th><td><table border="1"><tr><th>Fairfax Av.</th><td><table border="1"><tr><th>CMS</th><td><table border="1"><tr><th>action</th><th>address</th><th>machinie_id</th><th>portal</th><th>supplier</th><th>created_by</th><th>date</th><th>portal deficit</th><th>Load Value 1</th><th>Load Value 2</th><th>Load Value 3</th><th>Load Value 4</th><th>Load Value 5</th><th>Sub Load 1</th><th>Sub Load 2</th><th>Sub Load 3</th><th>Sub Load 4</th><th>Sub Load 5</th><th>Coordinates</th><th>Area Code</th><th>pending case id</th><th>project details</th><th>identification number APAC</th><th>site_id</th><th>state</th><th>status</th><th>timestamp</th></tr><tr><td>FP</td><td>1195 Fairfax Avenue </td><td>ZEBA 5841</td><td>NHE-9850</td><td>CMS</td><td>Administrator</td><td>2017/6/19</td><td>687965</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>Relay 4-12 Avery J</td><td>Tonal One B</td><td>2602700</td><td>Tertiary Node</td><td>0</td><td>Volume Sub < 1</td><td>passadena</td><td>PA</td><td>2017/06/19 17:35:56</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

**Here is my Python Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(Data.html)
print(df[3])
# shouldn't the index 3 return all the columns that come after "CMS"
```

i.e... columns : action,address, machine_id, portal.....till timestamp
Here is the snap of my html page:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shouldn't the index 3 return all the columns that come after "CMS"

What should be mentioned is that `pd.read_html` function returns

```
dfs : list of DataFrames
```

and `df[3]` would just contain the one of those dataframes.

---

To use table-header cells (`<th>action</th><th>address</th><th>machinie_id</th>....`) as column names - set `header` option to `1` (row number).

> *header* : int or list-like or None, optional
>       The row (or list of rows for a :class:`~pandas.MultiIndex`) to use to
>       make the columns headers.

Test:

```
In [21]: df = pd.read_html('data.html', header=1)

In [22]: df[3].columns
Out[22]: 
Index(['action', 'address', 'machinie_id', 'portal', 'supplier', 'created_by',
       'date', 'portal deficit', 'Load Value 1', 'Load Value 2',
       'Load Value 3', 'Load Value 4', 'Load Value 5', 'Sub Load 1',
       'Sub Load 2', 'Sub Load 3', 'Sub Load 4', 'Sub Load 5', 'Coordinates',
       'Area Code', 'pending case id', 'project details',
       'identification number APAC', 'site_id', 'state', 'status', 'timestamp',
       'Unnamed: 27', 'Unnamed: 28', 'Unnamed: 29', 'Unnamed: 30',
       'Unnamed: 31', 'Unnamed: 32', 'Unnamed: 33', 'Unnamed: 34',
       'Unnamed: 35', 'Unnamed: 36', 'Unnamed: 37', 'Unnamed: 38',
       'Unnamed: 39', 'Unnamed: 40', 'Unnamed: 41', 'Unnamed: 42',
       'Unnamed: 43', 'Unnamed: 44', 'Unnamed: 45', 'Unnamed: 46',
       'Unnamed: 47', 'Unnamed: 48', 'Unnamed: 49', 'Unnamed: 50',
       'Unnamed: 51', 'Unnamed: 52', 'Unnamed: 53', 'Unnamed: 54',
       'Unnamed: 55'],
      dtype='object')

In [23]:
```

Comment: I have two questions One: How would I be able to extract the values from the aforementioned columns, I.e.. Only header cols from "action" to "timestamp" and discarding all "Unnamed" ones , also would this work if say I have a similar nested HTML structure but with main columns coming not in the 3rd data frame but in the higher orders say 6 or 7 levels down , would I be able to use a regex on the entire HTML at once so as to extract the relevant column's and their values

Comment: use `.loc` method: `df[3].loc[:, 'action':'timestamp']`. As for regex matching consider `match` option of `pd.read_html` function

Comment: Thanks ,  the solution worked like a charm and helped me a lot